# How can I add multiple inputs to a SweetAlert2 popup?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have code on my website that uses a SweetAlert2 popup to let users request songs:

```
$('#request-song').click(async function() {
  const { value: song } = await swal({
    title: "Request a Song (please note song request won't be played unless we are live)",
    input: 'text',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Enter Artist - Song Name',
  });

  if (song) {
    $.post("functions/request.php", {request: song}, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    swal({type: 'success', title: 'Success!'});
  }
});
```

But when I add another input it will only read the second one. How do I add another input so listeners can include their name/username for shoutouts?

Comment: Please give more info. What is your requirement?

Answer (score 5):

From [SweetAlert2's documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#multiple-inputs):

> Multiple inputs aren't supported, you can achieve them by using html and preConfirm parameters. Inside the preConfirm() function you can return (or, if async, resolve with) the custom result:

```
const {value: formValues} = await swal({
  title: 'Multiple inputs',
  html:
    '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input">' +
    '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
  focusConfirm: false,
  preConfirm: () => {
    return [
      document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
      document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
    ]
  }
})

if (formValues) {
  swal(JSON.stringify(formValues))
}
```

Adapting this to your code:

```js
$("#request-song").click(async function() {
  const {value: songRequest} = await swal ({
    title: 'Request a Song',
    html:
      '<input id="song" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Song">' +
      '<input id="listener" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Listener">',
    preConfirm: () => ({
      song: $('#song').val(),
      listener: $('#listener').val()
    })
  });
  
  if (songRequest) swal(`${songRequest.listener} requests ${songRequest.song}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.3.5/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.3.5/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<button id="request-song">Request a Song</button>
```

The `preConfirm` property contains a function that returns the object that will eventually be returned from your `swal` call. Before, `swal().value` was a string: the name of the requested song. Now, it's an object: `{song: 'the song I want to hear', listener: 'me'}`. You can pass this object to `$.post` and modify `request.php` to handle it:

```
if (songRequest) {
  $.post("functions/request.php", {request: songRequest}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  swal({type: 'success', title: 'Success!'});
}
```

Or, if you don't want to modify the PHP, you can convert the object to a string and pass it that way:

```
if (songRequest) {
  $.post("functions/request.php", {request: JSON.stringify(songRequest)}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  swal({type: 'success', title: 'Success!'});
}
```

Comment: Okay so how can i go and add it to my discord webhook my hold code had: 

 if (song) {
      $.post("functions/request.php", {request: song}, function(data){ console.log(data); });
      swal({type: 'success', title: 'Success!'})
    }
   });

Comment: @JoshuaR Updated answer (and your question) with more information.

Comment: Oddly the form doesn't submit when hitting the enter key :<

Answer (score 0):

Note your selector `#request-song`, which is an **ID** selector. ID should be unique in a single web page, therefore the selector only returns the first matching element (I guess you are using jQuery).

To select multiple elements, try to use class or other types of selectors instead of ID selector.

For more information about CSS selectors, take a look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).